# Undefined color when using tikz inside beamer class

Tags: beamer

I am in the beamer class, and using tikz.  I want to use a color from the xcolor package, but am not able to get it working.  Here is my preamble.

```
\documentclass[usenames, dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
%\usepackage[font={small}, labelfont=bf]{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}


\usetheme{Cuerna}

%\usepackage{amsmath,commath,amssymb,amsthm,blkarray}
%\usepackage{bbm}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{array}


%\usepackage{siunitx}
%\newcommand{\imp}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
%\renewcommand{\vv}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
%\DeclareMathOperator{\inff}{inf \;}
%\DeclareMathOperator{\supp}{sup \;}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{physics}
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
\usebeamerfont{footline}%
\usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
\hspace{1em}%
\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=midnightblue}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[ball color=midnightblue!50!white, preaction={fill=black,
opacity=.25,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm, yscale=0.5}}] (0,0)      circle (0.6ex);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\title{Project}
\author{Name}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item something random
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have seen similar questions, but none of the suggestions have worked, such as loading in the package xcolor explicitly, or changing the order of when it is loaded.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `\documentclass[xcolor={usenames, dvipsnames}]{beamer}`? but difficult to test without compilable code...

Comment: The  dvips color is `MidnightBlue`, not midnightblue. Also the `usenames` option is obsolete: it's been the default for quite a few years;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- if you want to pass options to the `xcolor` package, use `xcolor={usenames, dvipsnames}`
- the name of the colour is `MidnightBlue` not `midnightblue`
- there is a missing `}` at the end of `\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{}%` (in its current form this command does nothing...)
- `\renewcommand{\vv}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}` won't work because `vv` is not defined previously

---

```
\documentclass[xcolor={usenames, dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[font={small}, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\usetheme{Cuerna}

\usepackage{amsmath,commath,amssymb,amsthm,blkarray}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}


\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\imp}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\vv}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\inff}{inf \;}
\DeclareMathOperator{\supp}{sup \;}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{physics}
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{}%

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=MidnightBlue}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[ball color=MidnightBlue!50!white, preaction={fill=black,
opacity=.25,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm, yscale=0.5}}] (0,0)      circle (0.6ex);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
content...

\begin{itemize}
\item test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: awesome thank you.  What a dumb mistake haha.  Anyways, thanks again

Comment: I also have the esvect package downloaded (where \vv is from), but I didnt include it here, because it wasnt really necessary, but thank you

Comment: This is also one of those occasions where the colour of the shaded ball shifts from CMYK to RGB (if the OP cares).

Comment: @DavidPurton Oh, right! Do you want to write a comment or answer yourself?

Comment: Nah. In this case the risk of the colour shift being noticed is minimal. It will make it more confusing to make it part of the answer. Leave it as the comment. In the end it's always going to be a problem whenever someone uses `dvipsnames` which are defined in CMYK. And I notice people prefer `dvipsnames` to `svgnames` or `x11names` which are defined in RGB for some reason.

Comment: I think Ill live with it, but thanks for the headsup, Ive had to redefine midnightblue manually anyways for aesthetic purposes, so I guess I could do that with CMYK rather than RGB

Comment: @Student You could also use the brand new `pgf-cmyk­shad­ings` package to fix the colour difference

Comment: @Student, define your midnightblue in RGB. Then you won't get anything unexpected with the shading. CMYK colours get silently converted to RGB in shadings and the colour looks different on screen. (`pgf-cmykshadings` allows shadings to be output in CMYK rather than being converted to RGB.)

Comment: sweet, is that the name of the package?

Comment: @Student, yes. See its [ctan page](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf-cmykshadings). (I'm the author of the package.)